# How to include the AddThis sharing buttons on the home page of a site?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using the [AddThis](https://www.drupal.org/project/addthis) module to expose sharing features for nodes to users.

Is there a way to include these buttons on the ***home page*** of a Drupal 7 site?

For nodes it's easy enough to add this as a field for each content type and have it show for each content type-based node. But I'm unsure how to add this for the home page.

Comment: Doesn't add this come with a block as well? You can easily expose the block and show it only on the page `<front>`.

Comment: @Neograph yes, you were right, I found the block that comes with the module and made it available just on the <front>. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the block that comes with the [AddThis](https://www.drupal.org/project/addthis) module and make it available (expose this block) only on the `<front>`.